# Dynamic UI element creation in Backbone

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js

I have dynamic generation of this.ui elements in Backbone:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
el : '[data-container]',
ui : {
//Needs to be dynamically generated
},
```

This is how I do it so far:

```
this.ui.protocolSetter = new $.fn.init("#protocol-" + id);
```

That works excellent. Now the question how can I do the same but using custom attribute.

If I have this HTML5 with data attribute:
     button data-something="1" type="button" ...

and I would like to dynamically bind the element but with custom attribute.

So far I have tried many combinations, including variations on:

```
this.ui.protocolSetter = new $.fn.init.(e.currentTarget.dataset.something);
```

and

```
this.ui.protocolSetter = new $.fn.init.find("[data-something='" + id + "']");
```

But nothings seems to work so far. What I am doing wrong?

Here is fiddle to illustrate problem more clearly:

jsfiddle.net/vA2N4

Comment: Can you post a little code to illustrate the problem more?  Are you having an issue with the ui object not having the appropriate jquery object when you go to use it?  My thoughts are that your jquery may be executing when the View is parsed, instead of when it is rendered... so the #protocol element would not be rendered yet

Comment: Hello Matty. The DOM is rendered and ready. I am successfully using ID of the HTML element to bind it to UI object. Having said that, I am positive DOM is ready. For example, same element has an ID and data-something (html5 custom). I can bind it using ID, but the issue is I don't know how to bind it using custom attribute. 

The HTML I inserted in first question is not shown for some reason, so let me try to recreate it a bit hoping it will provide cleaner explanation of the problem that I face. 

<button data-something="1" id="something-1" type="button">

Comment: Perhaps a little demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would help. Right now we can't see enough of what's going on to be of much help.

Comment: Most certainly. Here is the fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/vA2N4/

It is not functional demo, but it shows my issue more clearly.

Comment: Are you trying to do this? http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZaJpK/

Comment: Not really. Your example shows dynamic creation of UI by using ID as selector. I need data- selector to do the same thing.
If it is not possible to bind it using data selector, is there any other better way? Thank you for your time.

Comment: So what's wrong with `$('[data-something=' + id + ']')` then?

Comment: It is not binding it. I should receive this object on this.ui, but it is not there

Comment: I be damned. It is working. I could swear it did not recently. But it works now!!!. Please make this an answer, so I can vote for it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something more like this:

```
newBinder: function(e) {
    var id = e.currentTarget.id.replace(/^btn-/, '');
    this.ui.protector = this.$('[data-something=' + id + ']');
}
```

Note that I switched to `replace` to extract the number from the `id`, that's probably more reliable than `parseInt`. I've also switched to [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) to get the selector localized to the view's `el`, this can avoid problems with trying to find things that haven't been added to the DOM yet.

I'd also recommend that you create `ui` inside the constructor rather than as part of the view "class". This:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.ui = { };
}
```

will give each instance of the view its own `ui` whereas this:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    ui : { },
    //...
```

will attach the `ui` to the view's prototype and thus one `ui` would be shared by all instances of the view. This may not be a problem for you but bad habits are bad habits.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wNkqK/